# Graft blockchain

Tags: blockchain, database

I want to make a node to mine on p2pool, but i don't want to download 100GB of the blockchain.
Is it possible to skip downloading the beginning of the blockchain, like how git can graft when setting the depth to 1?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot "graft" the blockchain.